# can't acess hadoop cluster master via spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We are using cloudera's distribution for hadoop. We have a working cluster with 10 nodes. I'm trying to connect to the cluster from a remote host with InteliJ. I'm using Scala and spark.

I imported the next libraries via sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.196"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"
```

and I'm trying to create a SparkSession with the next code :

```
  val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("API")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
.config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://VMClouderaMasterDev01:9083")
.master("spark://10.150.1.22:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] o.a.s.n.c.TransportResponseHandler - Still have 1 requests         
outstanding when connection from /10.150.1.22:9083 is closed
[warn] o.a.s.d.c.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to 
master 10.150.1.22:9083
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)

    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
     ......
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from /10.150.1.22:9083 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInact
    ive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
```

To be honest, I tried to connect with different ports: 8022,9023 but it didn't work. I saw that the default port is 7077, but I don't have any process that is listening on port 7077 on the master.

Any idea how can I continue? How can I check on what port the master is listening to those type of connections?

Comment: Spark Standalone server doesn't typically run on 9083... That's the default Hive metastore port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Hadoop cluster, you shouldn't have a standalone Spark master, you should be using YARN

```
master("yarn")
```

In which case, you must export a `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable that contains a copy of the yarn-site.xml from the cluster

Comment: I'm getting now the error : "[SparkException: Unable to load YARN support]"

Comment: Did you actually download Spark with Hadoop support? Or are you only just including SBT dependencies? If only SBT,  you are missing `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn"`

Comment: I'm using only sbt and I added that dependency. Is it a must to download spark with hadoop support ? Right now, I'm not getting any error but I also dont see any rows that suggest that I connected to the cluster. After the session initalization I try to query a table but It just stuck..

Comment: When  I change the master back to local, I'm getting the next error : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw . So does it think that the hdfs is localy ? I dont have permissions problems on that directory on the hdfs..

Comment: Downloading Spark locally would allow you to use Spark shell for simple queries rather than your IDE. The answer to that error depends on your OS, but yes, you are required to have write permission on the Hive scratch directory. And it would not think HDFS is local if you include the hdfs-site.xml file from the cluster into the same directory as the yarn-site.xml set by `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.

Comment: The permissions I got on the hdfs directory is rwx-wx-wx. When I set the master to local I'm getting error for permissions. When I set it to yarn It takes a life time, I mean i try to return a df but I dont get anything its just thinking... Can you explain both issues ? my os is win7

Comment: HDFS permissions are fine. If you set master to local, that has nothing to do with reading from local or remote HDFS. If you're using Windows, you must have `winutils.exe` on your PATH to edit the Unix permissions of `C:\\tmp\hive` by default. And any YARN issues that you have may be network related, or your cluster is simply backed up using the default YARN queue... I can't answer that without actually logging into your cluster

Comment: I downloaded winutils and the current permissions on the c:\\temp\hive directory are drwxrwxrwx. So in order to open a session to the hdfs I must set the master to "yarn" ?

Comment: No. HDFS and YARN are completely separate things. Ones just a filesystem. The other is resource management. I suggest opening a new question that includes your `hdfs-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` because I suspect you're not using them and the defaults are being used (e.g. your local filesystem)

Comment: I will create a new question as you asked, thanks. In any case, I use the same files from the cluster.