# How to access remote HDFS cluster from my PC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I'm trying to access a remote cloudera HDFS cluster from my local PC (win7). As cricket_007 suggested in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842075/cant-acess-hadoop-cluster-master-via-spark/49842519?noredirect=1#comment86700903_49842519) I did the following things:

(1) I created the next Spark session

```
  val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("API")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
.master("local")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

(2) I copied the next files from the cluster :

```
core-site.xml
hdfs-site.xml
hive-site.xml
mapred-site.xml
yarn-site.xml
```

and configured the variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the directory that contains them

(3) I downloaded Spark and configured the variables SPARK_HOME and SPARK_CONF_DIR

(4) I downloaded winutils and set it in the path variable. I changed the permissions of /tmp/hive to 777.

When the master set to local I see only the default database which means it doesn't identify the XML files. When it is set to yarn the screen is stuck and it looks like my pc is thinking but it is taking to much time and doesn't end. When I use local and I also use the line `.config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://MyMaster:9083")` everything works well.

Why might this be happening? Why locally I see only the default database? Why when the master set to yarn I can't connect and it is stuck? And why when I add the config line it solved my problem only locally?

Comment: AFAIK `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is used by the Spark launcher **scripts** (e.g. `spark-shell`, `spark-submit`) which simply put that directory on top of the Java CLASSPATH so that Hadoop libraries find their config. If you don't use the scripts, either apply the CLASSPATH trick yourself, or just dump the files in Spark conf dir.

Comment: Whenever Hadoop libs don't find any conf files, they silently revert to hard-coded defaults. Which means, for Hive, creating a "sandbox" Metastore backed by a local Derby database. I guess your working dir contains a `derby.log` and a `metastore_db` directory...

Comment: I put the xml files in the SPARK_CONF dir but still it doesnt recognize the files and only the default database is available. I checked and indeed i have the files derbly.log and metasote directory and I saw that it loads a local database.

Comment: Did you inject that dir in your CLASSPATH, e.g. in property `spark.driver.extraClassPath` ?

Comment: The SPARK_CONF directory should be in my classpath ? In the projects directory ?